# Convert a H256 string to H256

Tags: rust, hash

I have a hash string `"0xf8dd02cc2a3174933fac4e87d7f6360c3cc67167db105b28d0bc434a60674e49"`. How can i convert back to H256.

I used function below but it return difference H256 `0xa8fb46593dfc218a4de6fcf14e0c9baa4bcf947b953c181689015793883b3a1d`

```rust
let hex_string = "0xf8dd02cc2a3174933fac4e87d7f6360c3cc67167db105b28d0bc434a60674e49".as_bytes().to_vec();
info!("{:?}", hex_string);
let hex_string_hash = hash::<Runtime>(&hex_string);
info!("{:?}", hex_string_hash);
```

---

```rust
pub fn hash<Runtime>(data: &[u8]) -> H256
where
    Runtime: frame_system::Config,
    H256: From<<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::Hash>,
{
    <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::Hashing::hash(data).into()
}
```

---

Edit: As [aurevoirxavier](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users/251/aurevoirxavier) answer. I have updated my code like this:

```rust
use primitive_types::H256;
fn main() {
    let hex = "0xf8dd02cc2a3174933fac4e87d7f6360c3cc67167db105b28d0bc434a60674e49";
    match array_bytes::hex_n_into::<H256, 32>(hex) {
        Ok(h256) => {
            println!("{:?}", h256);
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it like this `let hex_string_hash = hash::<Runtime>(&hex_string.into());`

Comment: why not use https://docs.rs/sp-core/latest/sp_core/struct.H256.html#impl-FromStr-for-H256 as above comment suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [array-bytes](https://crates.io/crates/array-bytes), see https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12190.

```rust
let hex = "0xf8dd02cc2a3174933fac4e87d7f6360c3cc67167db105b28d0bc434a60674e49";
if let Ok(h256) = array_bytes::hex_n_into::<H256, 32>() {
    info!("{:?}", h256);
}
```

---

For your steps, you should remove the `0x` prefix. It isn't a part of bytes.

With `array-bytes`, it will handle this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to remove '0x',you could use `Macro ckb_types::h256` in https://docs.rs/ckb-types/0.110.0/ckb_types/macro.h256.html :

```rust
use ckb_types::h256;
h256!("0xf8dd02cc2a3174933fac4e87d7f6360c3cc67167db105b28d0bc434a60674e49")
```

with cargo.toml:
ckb-types = "0.108"

Comment: I just mean. `hex` crate can not handle that. `array-bytes` will handle the `0x` automatically. Whether it exists or not. I prefer using a function instead of a macro.